# What does it mean "To hold up against scrutiny"

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, phrase-requests, phrase-usage

So I have this sentence: *"These books are very good and they **hold up against** both biblical and geopolitical scrutiny"* and I'm not sure what would that mean...

Comment: When you looked for "hold up" (intransitive) in a dictionary, what did it say?

Answer (score 1):

To me, the phrase "hold up against (or under) scrutiny" means that if carefully and closely examined, "it" will not change. Or, if you take the time to REALLY think something over, you'll arrive at the exact same conclusion reached at first glance.

Answer (score 1):

The phrasal verb is ***to hold up*** and in this context the definitions I would consider would be:

> to remain strong or successful AND if information holds up, it is proved to be true

> - e.g. Will his alibi hold up (= continue to seem true) in court? ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hold-up))

As for ***against***, it is used with the figurative meaning:

> directly opposite : FACING ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/against))

As for your sentence

> These books are very good and they ***hold up against*** both biblical and geopolitical scrutiny.

It means that these books will remain true and good even if ***faced*** (or examined) by "both biblical and geopolitical scrutiny". In other words, these books are so good that they can ***meet*** or ***rival*** any biblical and geopolitical standards.

Answer (score 0):

**hold up**

to continue in the same condition without failing or losing effectiveness or force

*She's **holding up** well under the pressure.*

Similar to ***stand up***

Comment: Yes I know that but the phrase up is "to hold up AGAINST" and this is confusing me...

Comment: Against here can be interpreted as facing.